# Java update system with a launcher

Tags: java, jar, system, launcher

I'm currently working on a quite complex update system for a multi platform Java desktop application.

I have a "launcher" that is updating my application files (call webservice, update files, etc...), then, the "launcher" execute a command to launch my application (command like "java -jar application.jar [...args...]).

This system is really efficient to update all my application files, but my problem is when I have to update the launcher.
For now, my solution is that the launcher update itself by downloading its new version, and calling a "swapper" program that replace previous launcher executable with the new one, then, the swapper launch the "launcher" again.
One more thing : the launcher is specific to the operating system, for example on Windows, it's a "*.exe" file. This is done to be able to associate application's specific files with a launcher etc...

This solution is not "sexy" but it works.

I would like to know if a better solution exist ? Something with a classloader or anything else ?

Sorry for my english.

Thank you

Comment: [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/) does all of this work already.  It is part of every Java installation.  All you need to do is write a short XML file, with a “.jnlp” extension.

Comment: Thank you, I already know jnlp, I missed one thing in my question : my launcher is the entry point of the user and is operating system specific (exe on Windows, to be able to associate file with it, etc...).

Comment: Java Web Start does file associations as well.  It also can create a desktop shortcut and/or start menu entry on installation.